# how to make barchart from date 1 until 31 with different value?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, highcharts

i have some problem with this.
i want to make a barchart with xAxis = day from 1-31 ( for this month)

this is my table: http://prntscr.com/4xaljv

case : i have average price Execpt the promo price : 1.000.000

how can i use that data to make a barchart like this one :
http://prntscr.com/4xal4p

anyone can help or make some sugestion about this case?

im trying using high chart and make some problem with value of each date.

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var chart1; // globally available
  $(document).ready(function() {
        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'column'
           },   
           title: {
                enabled: false
           },
           xAxis: {
              categories: ['1']
           },
           legend: {
                    enabled: false
          },
           yAxis: {
              title: {
                 text: 'Jumlah Penduduk'
              }
           },
                series:             
              [

              <?php

                for ($day=1; $day <= $num ; $day++) {
                  while($k<count($tglevent)){
                    if($day==$tglevent[$k]){
                        $promo = $hargapromo[$k];
                        break;
                    }
                    $k++;
                }
                if ($hargapromo[$k] != NULL || $hargapromo[$k] > 0) {
                    $harga_promo = ($promo+$data_rata2->average)/2;
                }else{
                    $harga_promo = $data_rata2->average;
                }
                 ?>
                    {
                      name: [<?= $day ?>],
                      data: [<?= $data_rata2->average ?>]
                   },
                  <?php
                }
              ?>
  ]
  });
  });   
  </script>
```

Comment: You need to parse dates to correct format (timestamps, for datetime xAxis), then set null values if you have no data in particular date.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT date, avg(price) FROM myTable GROUP BY 1
```

This will give you the average prive per day, no need (more speed) to calculate it in your program.

Note that you can use MySQLs data-Functions as well:

```
SELECT year(date), month(date), day(date), avg(price) FROM myTable GROUP BY 1,2,3
```